# UIPopoverController fails to appear on presentPopoverFrom

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

**EDIT: It was my fault, see answer below.**

I'm getting pretty confused as to why this isn't working now, I hope one of you guys can offer some suggestions:

```
// Initialise and setup the sharing view:
sharePopVC = [[SharePopViewController alloc] init];

// Create the pop-over we're gonna put it in:
myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sharePopVC];

// Confirm nothing is null or anything odd:
NSLog(@"sharePopVC = %@", sharePopVC);
NSLog(@"myPopover = %@",myPopOver);

// Present the popover:
// Not my ideal parameters but 'safe' ones:
[myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

// Does it even believe that it's visible.
if (myPopOver.isPopoverVisible) {
    NSLog(@"Popover is there, apparently..");
} else {
    NSLog(@"We concede the popover is NOT visible..");
}
```

Console output:

```
2012-04-11 17:31:37.345 sharePopVC = <SharePopViewController: 0x19c720> 
2012-04-11 17:31:37.348 myPopover = <UIPopoverController: 0x14b180> 
2012-04-11 17:31:37.349 We concede the popover is NOT visible..
```

And of course, nothing shows. I have almost identical code elsewhere working fine. What could be preventing it from appearing?

I've tried presenting it from a UIBarButtonItem, in case it was something to do with my rect but it didn't help. I've also tried forcibly setting the frame of my `sharePopVC.view` in case it was somehow all set to 0 and causing a problem but no joy there either.

`self.view` in this case is the main containing view with some subviews like a UINavigationController and UIScrollView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, and I'm sorry to say **it was me being stupid.**

I had `myPopover` and `myPopOver` **both** declared and I was jumping between them in the above, so obviously it wasn't working..

So I guess the lesson is; if something isn't working read it CAREFULLY!